# Perl Pass one of the Array in 'Array of Arrays' to a subroutine

Tags: arrays, json, perl, multidimensional-array

I am parsing a JSON file and I have one array of arrays @AllArgumentsArray .. The array withing this AOA are the sections of JSON through which I will traverse. A sample JSON is:

```
{
name: "myThing",
    value: {
    UveVirtualMachineAgent: {
        vm_name: "TuttyFruity"
        }
    }
},
```

Now the function I am writing will get many arguments like

```
&GetAnalyticsDataInHash($json,'name','value,UveVirtualMachineAgent,vm_name');

sub GetAnalyticsDataInHash{
    my @AllArgumentsArray;  #The rest of the arguments in an array
    my $decoded_json = $_[0];
    for (my $i=1;$i<=$#_;$i++){
        push @AllArgumentsArray, [ split /,/, $_[$i] ]; #split them and make array of arrays ..
    }

    print Dive($decoded_json, @AllArgumentsArray[0]), "\n";
}
```

The DumperShows that arrays are there in AOA .. but i am not sure how to pass a full array in Dive Function?

```
DB<5> p Dumper @AllArgumentsArray
  $VAR1 = [
            'value',
            'UveVirtualMachineAgent',
            'vm_name'
          ];
  $VAR2 = [
            'value',
            'get',
            'this'
          ];
```

Comment: What do you want the arguments to `Dive` to be when you call `GetAnalyticsDataInHash($json,'name','value,UveVirtualMachineAgent,vm_name')`?

Comment: There's no way `@AllArgumentsArray` contains what you say it does.

Answer (score 0):

The way to dereference the AOA and send it to Dive is

```
print Dive($_, @{$AllArgumentsArray[0]});
```

Answer (score 0):

`GetAnalyticsData` looks like it is supposed to accept any number of arguments of the "comma-separated path of hash keys" kind like `'value,UveVirtualMachineAgent,vm_name'`. So either you have to pass all of these to `Dive()` e.g. using an arrayref:

```
Dive($decoded_json, \@AllArgumentsArray);
```

or you loop over them and pass them to Dive one by one. Then you could just do it within the loop you have anyway and that could be more clearly written like this:

```
sub GetAnalyticsDataInHash{
    my $decoded_json = shift;
    for my $path (@_) {
        Dive($decoded_json, [ split /,/, $path ]);
    }
}
```

Of course you'll probably want to do smething with `Dive()`'s result but I can't tell without seeing this function.